# Хэширование паролей C#

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, хеширование, password-hash

Пароль в БД храню как строку. Есть метод для хэширования паролей

```
    public string Hash(string password)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
        password = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
        return password;
    }
```

В результате выполнения кода в строке отображаются "иероглифы" и непонятные знаки. Как это исправить? Какую кодировку применить?

Comment: У вас последовательность любых байт - соответственно могут быть любые символы. Раньше использовали heх представление. Сейчас чаще встречается base64. В отдельных случаях можно в бинарном виде (системный реестр)

Comment: `password=Convert.ToBase64String(result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Hash(string password)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
    password=Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    return password;
}
```